# Digits into array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, I tried to split the digits of an `int` and enter them into an array in Java. I don't know whats wrong, am I missing something when dealing with the array?

The array is declared like so:

```
    int[] digits = new int [100];
```

Here is the logic:

```
    while (r > 0) {
        // puts digits of n into array
        count = 0;
       sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            digits[count] = n % 10;
            count++;
            n = n / 10;

        }

        // squares digits[] and populates into sum
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sum = sum + digits[i]*digits[i];
        }

        // if sum is 1 then print 'Number is a happy number'
        if (sum == 1) {                
            addItems(b);
            r = 0;
        } else {
            r--;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as I've been looking through the web for a few days now and haven't found any real help

Comment: You need to post more of the code. I just did http://ideone.com/jJcCG based on your code, and it works just fine...

Comment: What actual problem are you facing, this looks like it should work...  Although, I wouldn't expect you to be able to get more than 9 or 10 digits out of an int, so your array is oversized.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my question, the code I've given you is to find if the number the user has entered is happy, I know this code works becsause I made it in C, but there must be something I need to change to make it work, any help?

Comment: @david: How is exactly is it not working? What is the expected output and how does that differ from the output that you get?

Comment: You explanation is missing the info like what you are trying to achieve and what you are getting (may some error or unexepted result).

Comment: Why do you need the "Integer.valueOf()" operator. Can't you just do sum += digits[i]*digits[i]; ?

Comment: Hey again, well Wwhen the user enters a number, say 100, I want it to tell the user if its a haooy number or not, in this cae 100 is a happpy number because 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1, when I try to output it, nothing shows up so I'm thinking there's an error in the code?

Comment: Did you try `System.out.println("Number is a happy number");` in `if(sum == 1)` and it's not working or what?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it doesnt work when I try to print

Comment: What is `r`, and why do you have a loop? Did you check the value of `n`? How does the `digits` array look like, is that correct?

Comment: Hey, I found out what was wrong!when I re-initialized sum = 0; after each looped it seemed to work! thanks everyone, rookie mistake in the end

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your code. However this is how I would do:

```
public int[] intToDigitArray(int number)
{
    int numberOfDigits = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10.0f)));
    int[] digits = new int[numberOfDigits];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; ++i)
    {
        int digit = (number % powerOfTen(i + 1)) / powerOfTen(i);
        digits[numberOfDigits - i - 1] = digit;
    }

    return digits;
}

public int powerOfTen(int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) return 1;
    return 10 * powerOfTen(exponent - 1);
}
```

Tested, and works:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intToDigitArray(1234445)));
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Are you sure this works, I copied it into a compiler and it did not work as expected. Have you made late minute changes? What about the input 0?